# Can Neural Network take multidimensional inputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, natural-language, recurrent-neural-network

I recently learned RNN and find that a common feature of it and CNN is that they use either a LSTM cell or Convolution to process a single multidimensional input (like images and word embeddings which size might be m*n) to a single number(assuming batch size = 1) and then use softmax or feed it into a neural network to get the final result. So I search for some cases of how a pure Neural Network can process multidimensional data like a image or a sentence. A classical way for image processing in a neural network is first flatten a 2D inputs to a vector (if an image is 64*64 then the size of vector is 4096) and this vector is going to be feed into a neural network which means at this time a single input becomes a number instead of a 2D matrix.

So my question is what if we don't flatten it at the beginning and just directly feed into a Neural Network (Fully Connected)? Is it possible? Is the operation between weights and inputs in Neural Network going to become element-wise like what it is in RNN?

The reason I ask this question is that from my point of view the position of each element in a 2D matrix might indicates some special information that you sometimes don't want to ignore, for example, no one flatten a word embedding matrix and directly feed it into a Neural Network for text classification tasks.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, preserving this spatial structure is exactly what makes *convolutional neural networks* so good at their job.

> Is the operation between weights and inputs in Neural Network going to
>   become element-wise like what it is in RNN?

I'm not clear on exactly what you mean by element-wise in this context, but the weights used in a CNN are shared across spatial locations of the input, inducing some sort of translation-invariance/equivariance prior.